# There is a gap, and I want my image to go there

Tags: html, css, image, position, overlay

I want to place my image in a gap, but I failed, here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kfboe8na/). As you can see, the right image and the overlay are not being placed as it should. I want them to be right in the gap from above.

HTML Code:

```html
<div class = "leftpart fadeInBlock">    
  <a href="http://www.google.com">
    <img src="images/test.jpg"/>
    <div class="flex-caption hvr-fade">Adventurer Lemon</div>
  </a>
  <div class = "sleft1">
    <a href="http://www.google.com">
      <img src="images/test.jpg">
      <div class="flex-caption hvr-fade">Adventurer Lemon</div>
    </a>
    <div class = "sleft2">
      <a href="http://www.google.com">
        <img src="images/test.jpg">
        <div class="flex-caption hvr-fade">Adventurer Lemon</div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "As you can see, the right image and the overlay are not being placed as it should." and how exactly should it be placed? can you please show us the picture?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Can you draw the expected result?

Comment: You have the jsfiddle and you should read the next sentence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see snippet

```css
.leftpart {
  width: 43%;
  margin-top: 0.7%;
  float: right;
}

.sleft1,.sleft2 {
  float:left;
  width:50%;
}

.leftpart a img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 130px;
  display:block;
}

.leftpart .sleft1 a img {
  
  display:block;
  background-color:blue;
  margin-top:4.5%;
}

.sleft2 a img {
  display:block;

  margin-top:4.5%;
  background-color:red
}


.flex-caption {
  width: 96%;
  padding: 2%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  position: relative;
  line-height: 18px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flex-caption {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  position: relative;
  line-height: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class = "leftpart fadeInBlock"> 
     <a href="http://www.google.com">
      <img src="images/test.jpg"/>
      <div class="flex-caption hvr-fade">Adventurer Lemon</div>
     </a>
     <div class = "sleft1">
      <a href="http://www.google.com">
       <img src="images/test.jpg">
       <div class="flex-caption hvr-fade">Adventurer Lemon</div>
      </a>
            </div>
      <div class = "sleft2">
       <a href="http://www.google.com">
        <img src="images/test.jpg">
        <div class="flex-caption hvr-fade">Adventurer Lemon</div>
       </a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

you had a bunch of problems both with your `html` and your `css`

**HTML**

if you want 2 `divs` to `float` next to each other you need to place them in `html` as siblings. your `.sleft2` was a child of `.sleft1` . you forgot to close the `</div>` for `.sleft1`

**CSS**

no need to write 2 different but the same styles for the `.flex-caption` divs. you can write only one style for both ( if you want them the same )

*IMPORTANT* you need to `float` the two containers `.sleft1` , `.sleft2` not the elements inside them ! so remove all the `floats` from other elements and add

```
 .sleft1,.sleft2 {
   float:left;
   width:50%;
 }
```

add `box-sizing:border-box` on the `.flex-caption` because if you don't, by using `padding:2%` the width of the `.flex-caption` exceeds  `100%`

+a few minor css changes

let me know if it helps

Answer (score 0):

```css
.leftpart {
  width: 43%;
  margin-top: 0.7%;
  float: right;
}

.leftpart a img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 130px;
  display:block;
}
.sleft1{
  float: left;
  width: 45%;
}
.sleft2{
  float: right;
  width: 45%;
}
.leftpart .sleft1 a img, .leftpart .sleft2 a img {
  display:block;
  background-color:blue;
  margin-top:4.5%;
}



.flex-caption {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 2%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  position: relative;
  line-height: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class = "leftpart fadeInBlock"> 
    <a href="http://www.google.com">
     <img src="images/test.jpg"/>
     <div class="flex-caption hvr-fade">Adventurer Lemon</div>
    </a>
     <div class = "sleft2">
      <a href="http://www.google.com">
       <img src="images/test.jpg">
       <div class="flex-caption hvr-fade">Adventurer Lemon</div>
      </a>
     </div>
    <div class = "sleft1">
     <a href="http://www.google.com">
      <img src="images/test.jpg">
      <div class="flex-caption hvr-fade">Adventurer Lemon</div>
     </a>
    </div>
   </div>
```